# Prove that if $x(t)$ solves $\dot x(t)=f(x)$ and $x(t_1)=x(t_2)$ then $x(t_1)$ is a fixed point.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that if $x(t)$ solves $\dot x(t)=f(x)$ where $f$ is continuous differentiable, and $x(t_1)=x(t_2)$ then $x(t_1)$ is a fixed solution. $t_1\ne t_2$. 
Explain by intuition and prove by: 1. Uniqueness and Existence Theorem 2. Analysis.

Firstly, what I didn't get here is what $x(t_1)$ exactly is. Is it a shifting of $x(t)$? Can I assume $t_0=0$ and then arrive at $x(t_1):=x(t+t_1)$?  If so, $g(t)=x(t+t_1)$ is also a solution of the equation, but I still don't quite understand. Can $x(t+t_1)$ go up and then down again(and vice versa) before reaching $t=t_2-t_1$? If it can't, then it must remain constant, but what happens next? If it remains constant it will intersect the $x(t)$. So basically, I am really confused. I would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: That would really upset me if I found out  it was a typo.

Comment: Sorry but you cannot continue to rediscover the theory piece by piece... See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_line_(mathematics)

Comment: I am not trying to unravel or to solve a mystery. I have my teacher notes, but sometimes I don't fully get the wording or don't fully understand what I am after, and having an outside assistance regarding individual problems help me understand different concepts, for this is practice, which means to me no less than theory.

Comment: Offtopic. In the present case, theory (as you call it, but, on further thought, I prefer to say the very concrete notion of phase diagram explained in the link I posted) makes the solution entirely transparent. Did you at least look at the link?

Comment: I did but I am still confused. I did, though, understand I have to show that $f(x(t_1))=0$, or at least think that.

Comment: If I understand it correct, either solutions are monotonous strictly or they are constant. Is it something I am allowed to assume following the phase? I was sure it am not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a one dimensional equation $\dot x = f(x),$ all solutions are monotonic. this follows from the uniqueness of solution and the intermediate value theorem. if $f(x)$ has any zeros, then between the zeros of $f,$ f has one sign.  the condition $x(t_1) = x(t_2), t_1 \neq t_2$ violates the monotonicity of the solutions, therefore $x(t_1)$ must be a constant solution.

Answer (score 1):

The differential equation should be one-dimensional. Then the assumption is that there are on a solution two points parametrized by $t_1\ne t_2$ with the same value $x(t_1)=x(t_2)$ and thus $f(x(t_1))=f(x(t_2))$.

By the mean value theorem (or Rolle), there has to be an intermediary point $t_3\in(t_1,t_2)$ with $f(x(t_3))=0$. However, this gives a stationary solution and thus a contradiction to uniqueness.